# How do I create a waterspout/vortex?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I need help on how to simulate a waterspout/swirl/vortex like the one in this image.

[image]

Comment: It would help to know what you have tried.  To me, it looks like the camera is positioned right at the surface of the fluid.  Perhaps the fluid simulation can be pushed to have an out(in?)flow at the bottom of the whirlpool, with some sort of push to make it spin?  It seems like this will require quite a lot of baking at high resolutions to refine the effect.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! We're glad to have you! This looks a lot like a Tutorial Request, which will likely get removed (they aren't what this site is about). Some newcomers get frustrated because they expect this site to work like a forum... but it doesn't. Please take a minute to review the [tour] and get a feel for how we do things in the StackExchange network (and Blender.SE specifically). Well asked, and well researched questions tend to get better answers. When you put in the effort to do your own homework, we feel better about putting in the effort to help get you the rest of the way ;-)

Comment: If you would like to see a similar file in action, http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/73563... Also, a search there for "water" may return a number of other files that offer suggestions.  I think Blendswap files are a cool way to see how others solve a problem I am facing... not always the one "right" answer is involved, and several techniques may be applicable...

Comment: A few related links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29130/how-to-collide-fluids-to-form-vortex and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np5aC97wZCg

Comment: Oh! I'm truly sorry about this question @Matt. I will try not to post like this next time. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Thanks @Gliderman, I have tried nothing so far. But I'll let you know what's up once I started.

Comment: I will check that out, thanks @rcgauer and @cegaton!

Comment: Lol, no worries @Vic ;-)